# What file format starts with 0xFEEDBABE?

Tags: router, file-format, hexadecimal

On my router, /mnt/jffs2/rg_conf1 and rg_conf2 begin with the following bytes:

`FE ED BA BE 00 00 ## ## 00 ## ## ## 00 ## ## ## 00 00 00 00 72 67 5F 63 6F 6E 66`

where ## is a non-ascii non-zero byte, possibly a length offset. This section is followed by 30 bytes of 00, then raw binary for the rest, which looks pseudo-random enough that it's probably encrypted and/or compressed.

What is this format? Can these files be decoded to human-readable config text (and re-encoded back)?

Comment: It’s most likely a proprietary format. It seems to be tied to the OpenRG platform.

Comment: you may be right, although a proprietary format inside OSS would be ironic.

Comment: If you think that’s ironic, you should probably stop looking at low-level OSS altogether. ;) Hardware manufacturers/IP core providers like it when their stuff remains obscured and provide blobs. Well, for starters you could name your router’s make and model.